# Is there a way to vertical look up then transport an entire row data in to proper columns in another sheet?

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Essentially I have a list of people on a mailing list. I need to find the people that are volunteers on that list and then transport that specific data into a volunteer worksheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mrRoGrK6Pv0X4AH7QdvoPPYa35oYh7kZIID4oyNAtcs/edit?usp=sharing

This is the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=FILTER({'data sheet'!A2:A, 'data sheet'!C2:C, 'data sheet'!B2:B}, 'data sheet'!D2:D="yes")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thanks this amazing and exactly what I need. let's say I need to leave a box empty in between like I want column B to be empty and phone to be C and email be D. How would I do that in my real spreadsheet the data actually starts from column D and there is stuff in between the data I'm trying to import

Comment: to be specific, name is in column B, email is in column E and the phone is in column F

Comment: you need two formulas then... paste this in **B2**: `=FILTER('data sheet'!A2:A, 'data sheet'!D2:D="yes")` and paste this in **E2**: `=FILTER('data sheet'!B2:C, 'data sheet'!D2:D="yes")`